# Determine Android sdk location from script

Tags: android, bash

I am writing a bash script to automate my Android build process. I need to run

```
android update project --path /bla/bla
```

If I didn't want to add the sdk tools directory to my PATH, and I didn't want to pass the script my sdk tools directory, is there a way for the script to determine the location of the sdk, so that it may run the `android` command?

Comment: Short of something like searching the *unspecified* system, or assuming something such as that some one of the tools would be in your path, that an ADB server process is already running, or that the project folder has been previously built with the toolchain leaving behind some records of itself?  No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be more specific as to what problem are you facing?

Maybe, you could search for the android command in your script and then run it.

This would search your file system ( "/" ) for the android command and store the full path in the variable execute_android

execute_android=``find / -type f -name android``

after this :

`$execute_android update project --path /bla/bla`

But, this would fail if you have another file named android on your system.

Comment: `android=$(find / -type f -name "android" -print -quit)` and then `"$android" update project --path /bla/bla` ended up working fine for now. Thanks.

Comment: Accepting answer, I had to add -print -quit to the find though for it to work correctly.